# Modifying previously written Azure page blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've come across something that I've always taken for granted because "it just works".

I have a 512 byte page blob that's been previously written to Azure.  Now I want to modify just one of the bytes in it, but leave the rest of the information in tact.  What's a good strategy for doing this?

When I was thinking about this problem I realized that hard drives do all of this for me; this is what I've been taking for granted.  Data is stored in a sector, yet I am able to modify certain parts of that sector while leaving the rest of the data as-is.

I'm honestly not even sure what this kind of data access is called.  I'm assuming I need to load the entire blob into memory, modify the bits I want and then write the 512 byte blob back, but that seems like a naive approach.

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`Put Page REST API documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691975.aspx), I don't think you have no other option but to download the entire blob (which is same as a page since your blob size is 512 bytes) in memory, update 1 byte and then upload that page.